# What is the advantage of using buffer objects for streaming vertex data?

Tags: opengl, gpu

What is the advantage of using a buffer object with `GL_STREAM_DRAW` data that is actually updated for every use over simply using a pointer to client memory?

As I imagine it, the data will have to be uploaded from RAM to the GPU every time anyway, so why is there an advantage in using a buffer object?

I imagined for a while that a disadvantage of using client memory could be that the driver would have to copy the memory contents aside to make sure it is not modified again or deallocated before the GPU gets areound to use it; but doesn't this go for data to a buffer object when calling `glBufferData` anyway? If `glBufferData` uploads the data from system memory before the call returns, couldn't a `glVertexAttribPointer` call that specifies client memory do the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

One big disadvantage of using client side vertex arrays is that they are not supported anymore in the Core Profile. So if you want to use the Core Profile, you don't have a choice.

With vertex data that changes frequently, in the extreme case for every draw call, you may also want to consider buffer mapping. Using `glMapBufferRange()` and `glUnmapBuffer()`, you can write your data directly to a VBO, which can save one data copy. The downside is that you have to be careful that you don't introduce synchronization points between CPU and GPU that harm performance. You can use schemes where you cycle through multiple buffers to reduce undesirable synchronization.

Very dynamic data is indeed the trickiest case when trying to use VBOs efficiently. I had some code in a hobby project that I originally wrote fairly long ago, using immediate mode at the time. In this case, all coordinates are dynamically calculated, and used exactly once. While almost everybody agrees that immediate mode is horribly inefficient (aside from being deprecated), my initial attempts of using VBOs for the same purpose resulted in the whole thing being... slower! It took some tuning, and trying various options, until I had it running at least as fast as the original.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting anecdote, but I can't really see that it actually answers the question. :)

Comment: The first paragraph pretty much covers the main part of your question. There really isn't another option, unless you want to use deprecated features that are not available anymore in current OpenGL versions.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes. That is relevant, of course. I admit I read it as kind of an aside, since all current drivers still support client-side vertex data and likely will for the foreseeable future. I would like the question to relate to the compatibility profile, for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

No, a `glVertexAttribPointer` call that points to client memory would not do the same thing.

That simply sets up a pointer. The server actually only reads the client memory in that scenario when a draw command is issued; adding to the overhead of draw calls. The real benefit to using a VBO comes from the fact that the server manages that memory, this gives the driver some smarter options to avoid stalling the render pipeline while you upload new data or unnecessarily copying client memory on ***every*** draw call.

I would suggest you glance over ["buffer orphaning"](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming#Server-side_multi-buffering_.28buffer_re-specification.2Forphaning.29) for a more detailed discussion of this issue. Buffer orphaning is the simplest strategy for optimizing this particular task, but if you are targeting a newer version of OpenGL there are some other more sophisticated strategies outlined there as well.

Comment: _"unnecessarily copying client memory on **every** draw call"_ -- But my question was precisely about the case where the data would have to be transferred on every draw call anyway.

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant by "updated for every use." I can imagine scenarios such as terrain rendering where you would stream new data and then issue multiple draw calls over different sections of the terrain. But if you have a 1:1 correspondence between modify and use, then that's not particularly helpful. It's still useful to have the server manage the memory though, one of the biggest problems with client vertex storage in the past was the difficulty implementing DMA data transfer - extensions were devised to improve this, but ultimately what won out was VBOs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying comment, but I must admit that I don't see that it answers the question. Correct me if I'm wrong.